Make subclass instantiate itself as a different subclass?
Let's say I have this scenario:
TMyControl = class(TWinControl);
TMyButton = class(TButton);


constructor TMyButton.Create(foo: TMyControl);
begin
   inherited Create(foo);
end;

I need a way to make TMyButton both a subclass of TMyControl and be a TButton.
Is there any way to do that in Delphi?
For example something like (obviously just wishful thinking pseudocode):
constructor TMyButton.Create(foo: TMyControl);
begin
   Self := TButton.Create(foo);
end;

If not, what other options do I have? The only thing I can think of is to yet again abuse the trusty old TPanel, making TMyControl subclass TPanel and making all its descendants (for example TMyButton) wrap their actual controls (for example a TButton) in a TPanel... seems pretty ugly though.

There is no way to declare a class descending from multiple parents. You'd better describe the reason why you think you need that.

Delphi does not support multiple inheritance of classes. You might consider exposing your custom functionality via interfaces instead, as a class can implement multiple interfaces.

@UweRaabe The reason is that I want all my subclassed controls to all share some functionality from the base class, but at the same time be instantiated as for example a TButton. So I guess another way of putting it is that I want to "insert" my base class TMyControl in the hierarchy somewhere between TWinControl and TButton... I realize it is not possible, but somehow it doesn't seem like a very far fetched use case either.

@RemyLebeau Thanks, that was my first approach, but of course it ended up falling short quite quickly since I want to implement methods in the base class, and possibly add fields as well.

@Magnus If the functionality from the base class that you want all subclassed controls to share is of the kind that does not need to be overridden with different variants in different subclasses, i.e. inheritance is not really needed, then you could make a class helper for class TWinControl. See https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/Class_and_Record_Helpers_(Delphi)

@Magnus "somehow it doesn't seem like a very far fetched use case" - but it is, because a standard TButton can't be a TMyControl, you can't inject a new base class into TButton's hierarchy. "I want to implement methods in the base class, and possibly add fields as well" - you can't add new fields to existing base classes.

@RemyLebeau: you can't add new fields to existing base classes Well, while that is true in the strict sense, you can give the appearance of doing so (see my 2nd answer).

A TButton is already a subclass of TWinControl:

So just declare TMyButton as
TMyButton = CLASS(TButton);

and it will be both a TButton and a TWinControl (as well as a TPersistent, TControl, TButtonControl, and TCustomButton).
You can't have it be a subclass of TMyControl as well, as that class is on a different branch. That's just not how CLASS ancestry works.

Right, I get that it is not possible to do multiple inheritance in Delphi. I guess another way of explaining what I would want to do is to basically "insert" TMyControl in the hierarchy between TWinControl and TButton, so that a TMyButton would have all the functionality of TMyControl while still being a TButton. I think this might be something like a mixin in some other languages. So my question then becomes - since Delphi doesn't have these features - is there a workaround? Surely someone must have had the same conundrum during the years that Delphi has existed.

@Magnus "basically "insert" TMyControl in the hierarchy between TWinControl and TButton" - sorry, that is not possible. You would have to derive TMyControl from TButton and then add whatever extra functionality you want to TMyButton. If you want other non-TButton controls to share the same custom functionality, then move the logic into a separate class/interface that all of your controls can share, but not through inheritance.

Delphi's class helper concept is close to the mixin concept.

@Magnus: It all depends on, what exactly it is you want to introduce in the inserted class. If it is just static methods and properties, then a CLASS HELPER will be an option. But you can't introduce virtual methods or (non-static) fields, as this would require that the source for the "lower" classes would need to be rebuilt since their allocations would not allocate sufficient storage to accommodate your added fields or slots in the VMT. You can hack your way around this by having a static dictionary with the added fields, indexed by the instance of the class, and properties to access these.

@Magnus: See my other answer for an example on how to inject new fields in an existing hierarchy.

If you want to add new fields in the middle of a CLASS hierarchy, then you can do it like this:
INTERFACE

USES ...
     Generics.Defaults, Generics.Collections,
     ...;

TYPE
  TExtendedClass= TWinControl;
  TMyControl    = CLASS HELPER FOR TExtendedClass
                  STRICT PRIVATE TYPE
                    TFields             = CLASS
                                            IntField    : NativeInt;
                                            StrField    : STRING;
                                          END;
                    TDict               = CLASS(TObjectDictionary<TExtendedClass,TFields>)
                                            CONSTRUCTOR Create;
                                          END;
                    TNotifier           = CLASS(TComponent)
                                            PROCEDURE Notification(Component : TComponent ; Operation : TOperation); OVERRIDE;
                                          END;
                  PRIVATE CLASS VAR
                    Dict                : TDict;
                  STRICT PRIVATE CLASS VAR
                    Notifier            : TNotifier;
                  STRICT PRIVATE
                    FUNCTION            GetFields : TFields;
                    FUNCTION            GetInt : NativeInt;
                    PROCEDURE           SetInt(Value : NativeInt);
                    FUNCTION            GetStr : STRING;
                    PROCEDURE           SetStr(CONST Value : STRING);
                    PROPERTY            Fields : TFields Read GetFields;
                  PUBLIC
                    PROPERTY            IntField : NativeInt Read GetInt Write SetInt;
                    PROPERTY            StrField : STRING Read GetStr Write SetStr;
                  END;

IMPLEMENTATION

{ TMyControl }

FUNCTION TMyControl.GetFields : TFields;
  BEGIN
    IF NOT Assigned(Dict) THEN BEGIN
      Dict:=TDict.Create; Notifier:=TNotifier.Create(NIL)
    END ELSE IF Dict.TryGetValue(Self,Result) THEN
      EXIT;
    Result:=TFields.Create;
    Dict.Add(Self,Result);
    FreeNotification(Notifier)
  END;

FUNCTION TMyControl.GetInt : NativeInt;
  BEGIN
    Result:=Fields.IntField
  END;

FUNCTION TMyControl.GetStr : STRING;
  BEGIN
    Result:=Fields.StrField
  END;

PROCEDURE TMyControl.SetInt(Value : NativeInt);
  BEGIN
    Fields.IntField:=Value
  END;

PROCEDURE TMyControl.SetStr(CONST Value : STRING);
  BEGIN
    Fields.StrField:=Value
  END;

{ TMyControl.TNotifier }

PROCEDURE TMyControl.TNotifier.Notification(Component : TComponent ; Operation : TOperation);
  BEGIN
    ASSERT(Component IS TExtendedClass);
    IF Operation=TOperation.opRemove THEN BEGIN
      Dict.Remove(TExtendedClass(Component));
      IF Dict.Count=0 THEN BEGIN
        FreeAndNIL(Dict);
        FreeAndNIL(Notifier)
      END
    END
  END;

{ TMyControl.TDict }

CONSTRUCTOR TMyControl.TDict.Create;
  BEGIN
    INHERITED Create([doOwnsValues])
  END;

The TFields contains the storage for all the extra fields. It only works with TComponent descendants, due to the use of the Notification system when the extended instance is released.
After including the above CLASS HELPER, you can do this:
VAR Button1 : TButton;

Button1:=TButton.Create(NIL);
Button1.IntField:=2;
Button1.Free;

(as well as all other TWinControl descendants).
If you want to include default values of the new fields, introduce a parameterless constructor in the TMyControl.TFields CLASS that initializes these.
I have made a declaration of TExtendedClass to signify the level at which you want to inject the new fields, in order to make it easier to move it around the hierarchy. Only limitation, as noted, is that it must be a descendant of TComponent in order to track when the extended instances are released (so I can release the TFields instance containing the extended fields).
